# How to calculate average value from gridded datasets in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, netcdf

Hello I have a gridded datasets in .nc format. I tried to read .nc file for different combination of latitude and longitude with the code given below, but i know this is not the ideal way to do that.

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
f= Dataset('data.nc')

data1 =  f.variables['asa'][:,3,23]
data2 =  f.variables['asa'][:,3,24]
data3 =  f.variables['asa'][:,3,25]
data4 =  f.variables['asa'][:,4,23]
data5 =  f.variables['asa'][:,4,24]
data6 =  f.variables['asa'][:,4,25]
```

and finally

```
data = np.vstack((data1,data2,data3,data4...))

Data = np.average(data, axis = 0)
```

Is there any simple ways to do that instead of reading every single grid and to calculate the average value??
yours help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about nc formatting, but I would expect that you should be able to do

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset

f= Dataset('data.nc')
Data = np.average(f.variables['asa'][:,3:5,23:26], axis = 0)
```

Comment: Yes Mikea, it is working but I am getting different answesr from these two methods :(. I dont know where is the problems

Comment: @ Mikea, the value I am getting is not a single array..see array([[-9.9989996 , -9.9989996 , -9.9989996 ],
       [-9.9989996 , -9.9989996 , -9.9989996 ],
       [-9.9989996 , -9.9989996 , -9.9989996 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.34800002,  0.3495    ,  0.17900001],
       [ 0.34750003,  0.38050002,  0.20750001],
       [ 0.31700003,  0.36800003,  0.33950001]],